# Xpath to find all elements following specific node

Tags: html, xpath

I have a specific html as shown below and i had observed that there is one specific h2 node that appears in all cases.

```
<div id='myDiv'> 
<..other elements..>
  <h2>Locator</h2>  
        <h3>Header 1 </h3>  
        <p>Paragraph 1.1</p>    
        <h3>Header 2 </h3>  
        <p>Paragraph 2.1</p>  
        <p>Paragraph 2.2.</p>  
        <p>Paragraph 2.3.</p> 
        <h4> test header 4</h4>
</div>
```

I want all the markups after the specific node the html format is as below.
As you can see i can locate the h2 tag by applying xpath `//div[@id='myDiv']/h2[contains(.,"Locator")]` but the trouble is finding all elements inside the div following the h2 tag.(I am not sure what types of tags can come after this h2 tag).Just to be more clear, What is the xpath to get the following nodes selected

```
<h3>Header 1 </h3>  
<p>Paragraph 1.1</p>    
<h3>Header 2 </h3>  
<p>Paragraph 2.1</p>  
<p>Paragraph 2.2.</p>  
<p>Paragraph 2.3.</p> 
<h4> test header 4</h4>
```

Comment: did it work for you?

Comment: Yes thanks, both //div[@id='myDiv']/h2[contains(.,"Locator")]/following-sibling::*
and  //div[@id='myDiv']/*[preceding-sibling::h2[contains(.,'Locator')]]
works. I had to choose one answer and I am choosing yours as you did provide extra demo code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`*[preceding-sibling::h2]` indicates all elements after `h2`. So after adding contains in the selector it goes like this

```
//div[@id='myDiv']/*[preceding-sibling::h2[contains(text(),'Locator')]]
```

See [Demo Here](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/46f0ebb0bd037994970b553a1eb03f36). Click The Test button you will get the result

Comment: *[preceding-sibling::h2] will be the element before h2 isnt it?

Comment: Place matters when you use this at beginning it will give you reverse result. So please have a try and let me know

Comment: This will not work properly if there is more than one `<h2>` with "Locator" in it.

Comment: @Tomalak Please look at his first line of question "I have a specific html as shown below and i had observed that there is **`one`** specific h2 node that appears in all cases.". his scenario is only for 1 h2 with `Locator` so i think there wont be any issue for him

Comment: Agreed, not in this case. The comment was pointing out a non-obvious gotcha, with the next person reading the answer in mind.

Comment: Yaah, well said. We also have to care about future readers (y)

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be looking for the `following-sibling` axis:

```
//div[@id='myDiv']/h2[contains(.,"Locator")]/following-sibling::*
```

Note, however, that the following siblings are, indeed, *siblings* of the nodes selected by the previous step in the path.  In your example, that's exactly what all the elements you want to select are (with respect to the `h2` node), but if any of those nodes had child elements, those child elements would not be siblings to the `h2`, and would not be selected.

If you want all those child elements as well, and their children, etc., then you could use the `descendant-or-self` axis, too:

```
//div[@id='myDiv']/h2[contains(.,"Locator")]/following-sibling::*/descendant-or-self::*
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `//h2[contains(text(),"Locator")]/following-sibling::*` for all the tags that are nested under the same parent as h2 but are "lower" than h2.